# Adding tabspace to CKEdiot

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor and i'm not great to JS and to modified CKEdiot. Are ther a solution to add tabspace to the editor. When i press the tabulator-button or i can also set a button to do it., but i don't know how !

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard tab button should take the focus away from the textarea to keep your form accessible.

To allow a user to indent/add tab space to content in the CKEditor you can include the "Indent" button on the toolbar. Use the "Outdent" button to remove indentation.

You can see these buttons being added to a toolbar on the CKEditor documentation for toolbars: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Comment: I want to set tabspaces between text's.. 
Like this. 
One apple                                   $ 10

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.tabSpaces

In config.js add new config line

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.tabSpaces = 4;
};
```

This should result in desired behavior

Comment: Hmm... Its not FCKEditor i'm using its a CKEditor, but its seems not working. it will tab out from the CKEditor and through the webpage.

Comment: I think I got your point. According to this, it is not possible without editing editor source code

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12443